# Creating Plus & Minus buttons using VBA using IF THEN Statements

Tags: excel, vba

I realize that I may be going down a rabbit hole here but it is worth a shot.

I am attempting to create one set of plus minus buttons in excel and have it apply to different cells on a separate sheet based on previously selected criteria.

I have searched all over and have found nothing.

Here is my example...

I have a staffing model where I want to forecast what will happen when I add or subtract employees. I am separating the employees by two types, Sales & Non-Sales. There are various titles within each type.

I am planning to reduce my Senior Sales Associate count by 2 FTE's and reduce my Sales Associate FTEs by 1.

I want to be able to use a data validation list to select "Senior Sales Associate" and then use a subtraction button to reduce by 3. I then want to switch my data validation list to select "Sales Associate" and use the same subtraction button to reduce that count by 1.

I was attempting to use Excel VBA If THEN statements but they do not seem to be working. I will provide an example of the code I thought would work below.

```
Sub Plus()

   If Range("A1")= "Sales Associate" Then
       Range("L10").Value = Range("L10").Value + 1        
   End If

End Sub
```

I am aware that this code will not account for multiple instances like I am asking, but it was not even working with one on the test. Please let me know if this is possible! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from the easiest and the smallest part of the code and try to make it work.
E.g. like this one:

```
Sub Plus()
    Range("L10").Value = Range("L10").Value + 1
End Sub
```

It should work, increasing the values of `L10` with 1.
Then, consider the `If` function. Probably there is some space at the end or something. Thus, try a simple if like this:

```
Sub Plus()    
   If Trim(Range("A1")) = "s" Then
       Range("L10").Value = Range("L10").Value + 1
   End If    
End Sub
```

The `Trim()` would strip the spaces from the left and the right of the checked string and would reduce the inner spaces to not more than 1. As a further check, it could be a better solution to use `LCase()` because "Sales Associate" is a different string than "Sales associate" and mistakes happen:

```
Sub Plus()

   If LCase(Trim(Range("A1"))) = "sales associate" Then
       Range("L10").Value = Range("L10").Value + 1
   End If

End Sub
```

At the end, if the code is in a module, then the ActiveSheet should be referred as well. Take a look at the dots before `.Range()`:

```
Sub Plus()

    With Worksheets("SomeSheet")
        If LCase(Trim(.Range("A1"))) = "sales associate" Then
            .Range("L10").Value = .Range("L10").Value + 1
        End If
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thakns. Works great. My next struggle is adding the second criteria (When A1 = "Senior Sales Associate" change L11 + 1) & having the addition happen  on a separate sheet (Lookup on sheet1 , add on sheet 2) Any thoughts?

Comment: @gbengel - You are welcome. For the second sheet, make sure you are referencing the worksheet completely - e.g. `If LCase(Trim(Worksheets("SomeName").Range("A1"))) = "sales associate" Then Worksheets("SecondName").Range("D1") = 324`